# Howto get the TreeViewItem from SelectedItem of TreeView

Tags: wpf, treeview, selecteditem

How can I access the selected TreeViewItem when i have a databound TreeView?

Comment: 1. This is not a question, if you want to share knowledge stick to the format. Ask a question and **answer it separately**. 2. You *really* shouldn't do this (use reflection to access private members that is)...

Comment: If to use reflection or not everyone have to decide his own. I think it is not always as bad as you might think. Some problems can't be solved clean without it (f.e. give a Toolbar new Stylekeys for Controls which are not supported out of the box --> The comments in sourcecode of the public symbols let you even see that the solutions MS uses are not always as userfriendly as they could be because of management decisions)

Answer (score -2):

I found an easy way to get the selected TreeViewItem from a TreeView even if the TreeView is DataBound. The key is a bit of reflection.

```
private static FieldInfo _selectedContainer = typeof(TreeView).GetField("_selectedContainer", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

public static TreeViewItem GetSelectedContainer(this TreeView treeView)
{
    return (TreeViewItem)_selectedContainer.GetValue(treeView);
}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Your comment is not really helpfull. At least write a reason why and not just vote things down because it is using "reflection". People spend sometimes hours of investiation when you working with really big trees because performance of normal solutions is to slow. The behavior of the default tree is not always what you need. Instead of directly writing your own control, why not to use possibilities which are there?

Comment: Well, it's obviously because accessing private members of a framework class is absolutely bad. How will your software react when Microsoft decides to change the framework implementation? And what happens if your software has then already been delivered to customers? Or don't you perhaps create production software, with a minimum level of robustness. I would strongly suggest not to propagate your simplistic quality demands here.

Comment: @Malone: You can even set private members using reflection; just because you *can* do something does not mean it's a good idea.